# Transportation cost flow optimization using Python Scipy Minimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, solver

I have a transportation cost flow problem and the purpose is to minimize overall transportation cost from 5 carriers and more than 3000 transport lanes (Ex. NY to MIA)
I will mock up some sample data from my dataset to help you have a better understanding of the problem. Please see my data image here

[image: Transportation Optimization]

I have tried Lonprog but it only works for lane by lane not for matrix decision variables

Please advise proper way to solve the problem without commercial solvers (standard excel solver has 200 variables limit)

Thanks

Comment: It seems you deleted your first attempt and improved the question somewhat. But it's still way too broad! Be **formal** in the description of your problem and try to make it understandable without the need for opening up external images (and images are also not easy to parse if someone wants to try your data).

Comment: In its current form it seems as your problem does not require a linear programming approach. You would just ship the entire volume over the minimum cost lane. Are there additional constraints that have to be considered for the problem?

Comment: Each carrier would have their own capacity of shipping as well,  A(80), B(120),C(200),D(60),E(50). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a nicely structured transportation problem. It can be tackled in various ways.

If you want to solve it with linear programming, you can use `scipy.optimize.linprog`. Encoding the variables is a little more difficult with multi dimensional decision variables.

With `scipy.optimize.linprog` you could model and solve you problem like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

LANES = 30
CARRIERS = 6

cost = np.random.rand(LANES, CARRIERS) # c
demand = np.random.rand(LANES) # b_eq
capacity = [250, 300, 500, 750, 100, 200] # b_ub

A_eq = np.zeros(LANES*CARRIERS*LANES).reshape(LANES, LANES*CARRIERS)
# Constraint for each lane, sum over the available carriers
for l in range(LANES):
    for var in range(l*CARRIERS, l*CARRIERS+CARRIERS):
        A_eq[l, var] = 1

A_ub = np.zeros(CARRIERS*LANES*CARRIERS).reshape(CARRIERS, LANES*CARRIERS)
# Constraint for each carrier, sum over the lanes
for c in range(CARRIERS):
    for var in range(c, LANES*CARRIERS, CARRIERS):
        A_ub[c, var] = 1

print(scipy.optimize.linprog(cost.flatten(), A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=demand, 
    A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=capacity, options={"maxiter": 10000}))
```

We need a total of `LANES*CARRIERS` variables, which can be represented in a one-dimensional array. The variable that expresses how much is transported on lane `l` with carrier `c` has the index `l*LANES + c`. Under this assumption the constraints can be added.
As the full problem matrix has `LANES*CARRIERS*(LANES+CARRIERS)` elements, the `linprog` function may not be suited for the problem size. You can increase the `maxiter` parameter, but you could run into other issues like numerical problems, though I did not read the source.

A faster and more robust free solver is bundled with `PuLP`. You can install `PuLP` with `easy_install pulp`. The problem can also be expressed in a more natural way, as `PuLP` has convenience functions for declaring variable dictionaries. While commercial solvers are faster than the one bundled with `PuLP`, your problem is a pure linear program and relatively "easy" even with 3000 lanes and 6 carriers.

In `PuLP` it can be implemented in a more natural way:

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

LANES = 30
CARRIERS = 6

cost = 100 * np.random.rand(LANES, CARRIERS) # c
demand = 10 * np.random.rand(LANES) # b_eq
capacity = [250, 300, 500, 750, 100, 200] # b_ub

prob = LpProblem("Transportation",LpMinimize)
x = LpVariable.dicts("Route", product(range(LANES), range(CARRIERS)), 0, None)

prob += lpSum(cost[l, c] * x[l, c] for l in range(LANES) for c in range(CARRIERS))

for l in range(LANES):
    prob += lpSum(cost[l, c] * x[l, c] for c in range(CARRIERS)) == demand[l]

for c in range(CARRIERS):
    prob += lpSum(cost[l, c] * x[l, c] for l in range(LANES)) <= capacity[c]

prob.solve()

# Get optimal solution
if LpStatus[prob.status] == "Optimal":
    x = {(l, c): value(x[l, c]) for l in range(LANES) for c in range(CARRIERS)}
else:
    print("Optimization failed.")
```

Comment: Is there a nice write-up on formatting the inputs for linprog?